# Install j2me application in samsung mobile

Tags: java, java-me, jar, installation

We developing j2me application for low end mobile devices (like Nokia s40 mobiles) which supports java. In our application we used JSR75 and JSR135 its working in nokia and sony ericsson but while trying to install the same application in Samsung devices(GT-S3310 ) we getting error like "File Format not supported". Please help how to install the jar file in samsung mobiles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How are you installing the app?  Side-loading the jar directly on to the device via USB or Bluetooth?  Some handsets don't support that.  Try installing it over the air instead, by pointing the web browser to the JAD which should be online somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

I already checked on some samsung mobiles. They could not allow direct installation through with bluetooth or with USB cable. Because they following certain security norms of java apps installation. You need to install it from WAP sites.

Comment: Bharath, can you give pointers to more information about security norms of java app installation, setting up a WAP site and connecting your phone to it?